# SQL SERVER 2014 Code Snippets missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, code-snippets, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to use the Snippets functionality in SQL Server.

I'm testing out adding new snippets to SQL Server 2014 following the instruction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130.aspx).

Everything works fine except that after I added the snippet, it doesn't show up in the IntelliSense. Even more, I realized that not all build-in Snippets are showing up.

I wonder if anyone else has the same experience, and knows how to resolve this?

This is a list of build-in snippets under `Function`

[image: build-in]

And this is what I see from IntelliSense (3 of them are missing)

[image: missing snippet]

Comment: can you share one of your snippet files please as it contains a bunch of info about how the snippet can be used.

Comment: @Tanner the only one I added is the sample template that you can find in my original post.  Or link here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is likely in the definition of the snippets.

If you inspect your snippets you should see a section like:

```
<SnippetTypes>
    <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
</SnippetTypes>
```

Or

```
<SnippetTypes>
    <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
</SnippetTypes>
```

These indicate where the snippet can and will be used from.

In a query window you have 2 options when you right click:

- Insert snippet
- Surround with

Which give you the different options as you can see here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This explains why you're not seeing the missing options when you try to insert a snippet.