# Can't find my snippets in ctrl K/X in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, code-snippets, ssms-2014

I imported them in this windows : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl2EC.jpg

but I can't find them in : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6P2l.jpg

Any idea why ? It's a fresh install of SSMS (and windows). Worked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you verify that in the definition of your snippets, you have sections like:

```
<SnippetTypes>
  <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
</SnippetTypes>
```

and/or

```
<SnippetTypes>
  <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
</SnippetTypes>
```

This indicate where the snippets can and will be used from.
*Source: [SQL SERVER 2014 Code Snippets missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701631/sql-server-2014-code-snippets-missing)*